# Normal map to height (black and white)

Tags: node-editor, normals, normal-map, height-map

How to convert normal maps (the colorful ones) into black and white maps (height) with some nodes to use them later?

Comment: There are some free tools doing that kind of conversion: Substance Bitmap to Material, Njob, XNormal etc. which are preferable because you have plenty of options. But if you want nodes in Blender, here is a technique worth mentioning ( at 1:50 minutes into the tutorial, first part is about ao): https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=PILPNNexW1w

Comment: @radoo thanks. do you know if this is possible in the shader editor? i cant find the same nodes. also he is using the depth map and not an normal map. or is it the same?

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid it's not possible in the shader editor, at least I never heard about it. May I ask why is it important to be in the shader editor?